# getting this AtrributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save' in Python | PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, attributeerror

I'm getting this error only when the program finishes running. This program consumes an api, generally it "downloads" the images (250 images), resizes and returns me in a new folder created with "os".

I already researched about the error, but nothing solved it and usually the error happens right at the time of saving and it's happening to me after everyone is already saved

code:

```
import requests
import os
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

request = requests.get("https://mocki.io/v1/9a7c1ca9-29b4-4eb3-8306-1adb9d159060").json()

filmes = request["items"]

os.makedirs('stickers')

for filme in filmes:
    image = requests.get(filme['image']).content
    try:
        image = Image.open(BytesIO(image))
        image.thumbnail((600,600))
        image.save(optimize=True, quality=40)
    except: pass
    with open(os.path.join("stickers", filme['title'] + ".jpg"), "wb") as img:
        image.save(img)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: Also, if you're getting errors, `except: pass` is generally not a very good idea.

Comment: what return status are you getting from the `requests.get` line?  

also, your 2nd `try/except` does not seem like it is a good idea unless you specify a more specific Exception to catch.

Comment: @MattDMo how come "post the full text of any erros or tracebacks"? i didn't get it,  so sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change the previous instruction so it has a full path:

```
    for film in films:
       image = requests.get(film['image']).content
        try: 
          os.makedirs('C:/stickers')
        except:
          pass
```

Then, add the fp= parameter to image.save as below, as well as change the exception:

```
    try:

       image = Image.open(BytesIO(image))
       image.thumbnail((600,600))
       image.save(optimize=True, quality=40, fp=os.path.join("c:/stickers", film['title'] + ".jpg"))

    except Exception as e:

       print(e)
```

please see a screen shot [sample code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxZGR.png)

Comment: hi, so, did like you said and then i received this error for every single "image"

```[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:/stickers/Barry Lyndon.jpg'```

Comment: Oh, sorry. First you need to create the directory. In the previous line make sure to add the full path as well in for film in films:
    image = requests.get(film['image']).content
    try: os.makedirs('C:/stickers')

Comment: Please see a sample code here https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxZGR.png

Comment: now i get this for all files, stickers folder is created, all images are going there ```[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:/stickers/Memories of Murder.jpg'```,

and i keep getting this in the end
    ```image.save(img)
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'save'```

Comment: Please see it here https://github.com/saurater/PythonFundamentos/blob/master/Image_Loading_Example.ipynb

Comment: Rotated, amazing. But now get it ```cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fcf37e240e0>``` but i believe that it's one photo because when i look into the file, i have 249 images...

Comment: i believe that the "pass" at the except would be a "good" solution?

Comment: I would also like to ask, why use try/except with ```os.makedirs``` if it works without error outside the scope of the loop?

for exemple on top of the for loop

Comment: https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZGJlOWE1MDItZWQ4Zi00NGRmLTk0NDYtMmM2MTEwZDkwNjlkXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_UX128_CR0,3,128,176_AL_.jpg

Comment: Please see V2 at https://github.com/saurater/DataScienceBootcampIGTI_Alexsander_Statsmodelss/blob/main/Image_Loading_Example_V2.ipynb. 

It will show you which file is not availale as an output print

This file is not availble

The Seventh Seal

https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZGJlOWE1MDItZWQ4Zi00NGRmLTk0NDYtMmM2MTEwZDkwNjlkXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_UX128_CR0,3,128,176_AL_.jpg

I suppose your initial question has been answered. If so,  please evaluate it and close it

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is that you are catching your errors from

```
try:
    image = Image.open(BytesIO(image))
    image.thumbnail((600,600))
    image.save(optimize=True, quality=40)
except: pass
```

and simply doing 'pass'.
This means if an error occurs in that try-catch block you would have no idea, and it would be completely silent.

What is likely happening is that you failed to retrieve the network resource at the following line:

```
 image = requests.get(filme['image']).content
```

So the image variable is None when you try and do Image.open(), causing an error, but you catch that error, pass it and then the image is STILL None, so you get a second error on .save()

#### Recommendations

1. At least log the error details in your `except` block.
2. Handle the case where you have a failed request - network requests are not guaranteed, and OS operations on files are also not guaranteed - that is why they can throw errors. They are there to inform you of issues that have occurred and that an operation has failed.

Comment: hey, the images are downloaded with the modified dimensions, so how could they be None? i'm not sure if i get it correctly, if not, i'm sorry!

Comment: That was a guess on my part. The key here is to log your error in your try-catch block, because you are likely hiding the actual error.

They could be None for a number of reasons, due to assumptions by you the programmer. And we won't be able to tell until you provide the additional error from the try catch block.

Comment: i got it, it was a mistake on my part. however i fixed it, please, have a look at it.

```os.makedirs('stickers')

for filme in filmes:
    image = requests.get(filme['image']).content
    try:
        image = Image.open(BytesIO(image))
        image.thumbnail((600,600))
        image.save(optimize=True, quality=40)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    with open(os.path.join("stickers", filme['title'] + ".jpg"), "wb") as img:
        image.save(img)
```

and now i get this error in try/except: ```Image.save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fp'```

Comment: but as you can see it the other section https://stackoverflow.com/a/73187320/19661764 when i add the 'fp', it returns me the first error